deriving differential equation from difference of PDE solutions
Consider defining $$f(x,t)=g(x,t)-h(x,t)$$ where the PDEs describing $g(x,t)$ and $h(x,t)$ are $\it{known}$ but the solutions themselves are $\it{unknown}$. It could be impractical to solve the PDEs for $g(x,t)$ and $h(x,t)$ for whatever reason. But recovering the differential equation for $f(x,t)$ could be useful.
I want to determine if a PDE or ODE and be derived for $f(x,t)$ and for which family of PDEs, if any. That is the more general problem.
Specifically for my case the PDEs for $g(x,t)$ and $h(x,t)$ have the form
$$
a_0\dfrac{dg}{dt}+a_1+a_2\dfrac{dg}{dx}+a_3\left(\dfrac{dg}{dx}\right)^2+a_4\dfrac{d^2g}{dx^2}+a_5g=0
$$
$$
b_0\dfrac{dh}{dt}+b_1+b_2\dfrac{dh}{dx}+b_3\left(\dfrac{dh}{dx}\right)^2+b_4\dfrac{d^2h}{dx^2}+b_5h=0
$$
The solutions for $g(x,t)$ and $h(x,t)$ are known and are quadratic functions of $x$, via guess-and-check method and solving the reduced ODE system. Additionally note they have the same form but differ in coefficients.
Because a combination of solutions might not reduce to a known combination of differential equations, I don't know how to proceed. Even referencing a thorough, accessible guide would help.
MY ATTEMPT: Using a differential operator consistent with above PDEs, let
$$
\mathcal{D}(z)=c_0\dfrac{dz}{dt}+c_1+c_2\dfrac{dz}{dx}+c_3\left(\dfrac{dz}{dx}\right)^2+c_4\dfrac{d^2z}{dx^2}+c_5z
$$
Now applying $\mathcal{D}(z)$ to $f(x,t)$,
$$
\mathcal{D}(f)=c_0\dfrac{df}{dt}+c_1+c_2\dfrac{df}{dx}+c_3\left(\dfrac{df}{dx}\right)^2+c_4\dfrac{d^2f}{dx^2}+c_5f
$$
$$
=c_0\dfrac{dg}{dt}-c_0\dfrac{dh}{dt}+c_1+c_2\left(\dfrac{dg}{dx}-\dfrac{dh}{dx}\right)+c_3\left(\dfrac{dg}{dx}-\dfrac{dh}{dx}\right)^2+c_4\left(\dfrac{d^2g}{dx^2}-\dfrac{d^2h}{dx^2}\right)+c_5(g-h)
$$
Now expand quadratic term,
$$
=c_0\dfrac{dg}{dt}-c_0\dfrac{dh}{dt}+c_1+c_2\left(\dfrac{dg}{dx}-\dfrac{dh}{dx}\right)+c_3\left(\dfrac{dg}{dx}\right)^2+2c_3\left(\dfrac{dg}{dx}\right)\left(\dfrac{dh}{dx}\right)+c_3\left(\dfrac{dh}{dx}\right)^2+c_4\left(\dfrac{d^2g}{dx^2}-\dfrac{d^2h}{dx^2}\right)+c_5(g-h)
$$
Now match the straightforward coefficients with those of other PDEs.
$$c_0=a_0-b_0$$
$$c_1=a_1-b_1$$
$$c_2=a_2-b_2$$
$$c_3=?$$
$$c_4=a_4-b_4$$
$$c_5=a_5-b_5$$
If this path is correct, is there a way to solve for a coefficient using a substitution or something?  Or is this impossible?

it is a bit unclear to me why would you need this since you already have two nonlinear-pdes for $g,h$, and so you can just ,say, numerically solve them separately and then simply subtract their difference to get f.

Thank you for your time.  I wanted to investigate a way to either determine $f$ analytically without numerically solving the components or have a viable differential equation for $f$ that could be less expensive computationally to solve for more complex situations.  I mention in the post those PDEs have analytical solutions but I want to use them as a test-case for the general idea.  Does this help?

since the pde has that squared term, you will likely not get any simpler PDE for $f$. If you have some white-noise or degenerate potential +V, then yes because they would cancel out. But here are you are stuck with products gh.
